# Public Apache2 Server

Tags: apache2, public, static-ip-address

I wonder how to make my apache2 server public?
I mean, I have a static ip and someone who knew that ip can access my website from out-world.
I already install apache2. I test it from http://localhost, I mean its working.

My OS is ubuntu by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that your Apache configuration has it listening for connections on all IPs, or at least the externally-visible IP address: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen

You can verify this by using the command `netstat -anp | grep apache` (maybe `:80` would be easier than `apache`).

Comment: Thanks sarnold;

But I'm new. Where do I write the command "Listen 80"? Do I write it "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"?

As soon as I manage this my web page or web page under /var/www, will become accessible form out-world?